Airflow BigQueryToMsSqlOperator mssql_conn_id issue
I have a problem with the deployment of the BigQueryToMsSqlOperator operator. The prolem is that the DAG does not replace the operator I defined, it tries to connect with the default one (‘mssql_default’). This is strange because the database connection variable works correctly on the other operator in this DAG.
What could be the reason for this action? Has anyone perhaps faced similar behaviour and solved it?
E: More information
Yeah sure.
here is my code:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_mssql import BigQueryToMsSqlOperator
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import pendulum


dagShortName =          'xxx'
dagName =           'xxx'
mssql_conn_id =         'my_con'
gcp_conn_id =           'my_gcp'
default_args = {
    'start_date' :      pendulum.datetime(2024, 5, 19)
    'retires' :         0
    'retry_delay' :     timedelta(minutes=1)
    }


schedule_interval =         '0 17 * * *'

with DAG(
    dagName,
    default_args = default_args,
    description = dagDesc,
    catchup = False,
    schedule_interval = schedule_interval

) as dag:
    transfer_task = BigQueryToMsSqlOperator(
    task_id = 'xxx',
    source_project_dataset_table = 'my_proj.my_detaset.mytable',
    target_table_name = 'mysqlproj.mysqldataset.mysqltable',
    mssql_conn_id = mssql_conn_id
    )


transfer_task

Airflow version 2.5.3
I have to raws from logs:
INFO - Using connection ID 'mssql_default' for task execution
pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009 Unable to connect
I have ruled out:

an error in the DAG

an error with the connection in the Airflow UI


expects the defined value to be substituted for mysql_conn_id

Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange community. In order for us to help you, could you provide some code you wrote, you might also want to share the version of Airflow and the version of the Operator. It also usually nice to provide logs of the output your facing and what's the expected behavior.

Thank you for message, I added information in my post

Are you Using a MySQL Connection or just a regular Airflow Variable ?

Connection in Airflow. Like here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/howto/connection.html
